# Laravel sanctum как совмещать middleware для авторизованного и неавторизованого по токену пользователя?

Tags: laravel, sanctum

Допустим у меня есть маршрут в `routes/api.php`

```
/api/example
```

По этому маршруту есть контент и он отличается в зависимости от того, авторизовался пользователь или нет. Если я защищаю его стандартно через `auth:sanctum`, то контент по этому маршруту может получить только авторизированый по токену пользователь, все остальные получат `401 ответ сервера`. Но тогда мне прийдётся создавать 2 отдельных маршрута, один защищенный, а другой нет, что бы предоставить доступ для неавторизованного пользователя. Вопрос, как можно совместить в одном маршруте контент для авторизованного и неавторизованного пользователя, ведь куки не получается отправить с мобильного приложения.

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('/example', ExampleController::class );
```

Comment: А в чём смысл этого когда контент один? Зачем авторизация когда неважно зареган я или нет, я получу тот же контент. Оставьте 1 маршрут и всё

Comment: @DmitriiSedov  там же написано в вопросе, контент разный и зависит от того авторизован пользователь или нет.  Думал, что у меня достаточно типичная проблема, но почему то никто с таким не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать мидлвару auth

```
Route::middleware('auth')->post('/api/example', ExampleController::class );
```

и внутри контролера проверять через `Auth::check();`

чтобы это cработало надо в конфигах **/app/auth.php**

заменить дефолтный guard

```
'defaults' => [
    // 'guard' => 'web',
    'guard' => 'sanctum',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```